# Why aren't these two bits of JavaScript equivalent?

Tags: javascript, firebug, closures, jquery

in jquery 1.4.2, ff 3.6.6:

The following code produces three divs, which write messages to the firebug console as you would expect.  However, if you uncomment out the loop and comment out the 3 lines doing it manually, it doesn't work - mousing over any of the divs results in `"three"` being written to the console.

Why are these two methods any different than each other?  In each one you use a selector to find the element and add an event to it.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$( document ).ready( function() {

  $("#one").mouseenter(function(){console.log("one")})
  $("#two").mouseenter(function(){console.log("two")})
  $("#three").mouseenter(function(){console.log("three")})

  //  names=['one','two','three'];
  //  for (k in names){
  //    id=names[k]
  //    $("#"+id).mouseenter(function(){console.log(id)})
  //  }
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="one">ONE</span>
  <p><span id="two">TWO</span></p>
  <p><span id="three">THREE</span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please start with fixing your HTML. You have two unclosed <p> tags.

Comment: You should declare your variables unless you want them to be global variables. `var names = ['one', 'two', 'three'];`, `for (var k in names) {`, `var id`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would be having [a very common closure problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) in the `for in` loop.

Variables enclosed in a closure share the same single environment, so by the time the `mouseenter` callback is called, the loop will have run its course and the `id` variable will be left pointing to the value of the last element of the `names` array.

This can be quite a tricky topic, if you are not familiar with how closures work. You may want to check out the following article for a brief introduction:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: Working with Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

You could solve this with even more closures, using a function factory:

```
function makeMouseEnterCallback (id) {  
  return function() {  
    console.log(id);
  };  
}

// ...

var id, k,
    names = ['one','two','three'];

for (k = 0; k < names.length; k++) {
  id = names[k];
  $("#" + id).mouseenter(makeMouseEnterCallback(id));
}
```

You could also inline the above function factory as follows:

```
var id, k, 
    names = ['one','two','three'];

for (k = 0; k < names.length; k++) {
  id = names[k];
  $("#" + id).mouseenter((function (p_id) {  
    return function() {  
      console.log(p_id);
    };  
  })(id));
}
```

Any yet another solution could be as [@d.m suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287500/why-arent-these-two-bits-of-javascript-equivalent-jquery/3287561#3287561), enclosing each iteration in its own scope:

```
var k, 
    names = ['one','two','three'];

for (k = 0; k < names.length; k++) {
  (function() {
    var id = names[k];
    $("#" + id).mouseenter(function () { console.log(id) });
  })();
}
```

Although not related to this problem, it is generally recommended to avoid using a `for in` loop to iterate over the items of an array, as [@CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) pointed out in a comment below ([Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)). In addition, explicitly terminating your statements with a semicolon is also considered a good practice in JavaScript.

Comment: Good answer (+1) but would be even better if you showed him how to do it in a loop by new-ing up new strings for the IDs.

Comment: Also, although is not the problem, I'll not ever get tired of recommending to **avoid** the `for-in` statement for "iterate" over array objects. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848)

Comment: @Bernhard: Thanks... I'll update my answer with a couple of solutions :)

Comment: Small typos, the function name on the first example, and immediate invocation of the anonymous function of the second are missing.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when the code of the anonymous function `function(){console.log(id)}` is executed, the value of `id` is `three` indeed.

To can use the following trick to enclose the value on each loop iteration into the anonymous callback scope:

```
names=['one', 'two', 'three'];
for (var k in names) {
    (function() {
        var id = names[k];
        $("#"+id).mouseenter(function(){ console.log(id) });
    })();
}
```

Comment: It will not work, because `id` is undeclared and it will become a property of the global object (`window.id`). You need to bind it to the new variable environment (use `var`!).

Comment: : You're welcome. Be aware also that `k` will become global, and that the purpose of the `for-in` statement isn't really to *iterate* over the indexes of array objects, it's purpose is to *enumerate* object properties.

Comment: @CMS, oh, dang, sorry; just awaken, not in this world yet.

I know about for-in; personally I'd prefer the
    `for (var i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`
loop in this case, but as I said already, I just copied the fastmultiplication's code.

Comment: : No problem! Yeah, any *secuential loop*, and if the order of iteration is not important a reverse loop e.g. `var i = names.length; while (i--) {/**/}` is enough. Cheers!